# Testing node.js Command Line tool with Jest

Tags: javascript, nodes, jestjs

I'm currently trying to get some test coverage for a command line tool I built in node with Jest. My code is split up in modles, most of which have asynchronous http requests that I'm trying to mock. I'm wondering if there is a way to mock these requests that exist inside the module functions?

```
module.exports = function() {
  client.apiGet() // How do I mock this?
    .then(() => {
      // more logic, runs several fs operations
    })
    .catch((err) => { console.error(err) });
}
```

Comment: Where does `client` come from?

Comment: @JordanRunning client comes from a separate module that holds all the client requests. I've created mock functions for these requests that return json values without making the http request.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to mock the `client` module. I assume you had `require` or `import` it further up. Once you have it mocked you can decide to either stub all of it's methods' implementations or just the `apiGet`. 
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks.

Finally, you will probably use the `.resolves` and `.rejects` to have the proper expectation.
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#resolves

@Koen Van Gilst wrote a great blog about mocking API calls with Jest: 
https://hackernoon.com/api-testing-with-jest-d1ab74005c0a

Hope this sends you in the right direction